# How to select the target platform in clang?

Tags: windows, clang, llvm

Currently, I am using the command:

```
clang++ -o hello.exe hello.cpp
```

Is there any way to set the target platform, for example if I wanted to build targeting `x86` or `ARM` on my `x64` computer. In visual studio, you can easily set this under configurations. I am using `clang` front end and `LLVM` back end.

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697614/clang-cross-compiling-for-arm , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70122891/clang-cross-compile-for-raspberry-pi-3b etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clang Cross Compiling for ARM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697614/clang-cross-compiling-for-arm)